# Gnome-Shell Dashboard like application for KDE

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, mac-dashboard-widget

I have seen that XFCE with xfdashboard created a solution which basically does what Gnome-Shell is capable of. Is there a similar dashboard that plays well with KDE Plasma 5? Something this is more Applet oriented?

Comment: really off-topic on stackoverflow; anyway, plasma 5.4 released a new dashboard

Comment: You might be right. KDE actually has Dashboard, but it behaves differently. If someone wants a behave like that, why not use Gnome Shell at all? The new dashboard looks very nice though.

Answer (score 0):

In Plasma >= 5.4 there is a [Application Launcher Dashboard](https://www.kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.4.0.php) (see section Application Dashboard alternative launcher). You can see it in action [for instance for instance here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE9fV8II6eI&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: Yes, that's right and really nice to have. Nevertheless you have two corners or buttons, one for launcher and another one for the windows manager, expose view, while in Gnome Shell there only is "Activities" corner/button. Application Launcher Dashboard still has some bugs though, but cool idea and it sure will improve a lot.